Run rpc node connection timed out Unable to determine the validator's public IP address
I'm trying to setting up a rpc node for Solana on a rented Hetzner Server.
I have followed the official documentation's guide https://docs.anza.xyz/operations/setup-a-validator here.
I have modified the variables in the validator.sh file to change it from a validator to a simple rpc node.
My validator.sh file is that one:
#!/bin/bash
exec agave-validator 
--identity /home/sol/validator-keypair.json 
--known-validator 5D1fNXzvv5NjV1ysLjirC4WY92RNsVH18vjmcszZd8on 
--known-validator dDzy5SR3AXdYWVqbDEkVFdvSPCtS9ihF5kJkHCtXoFs 
--known-validator eoKpUABi59aT4rR9HGS3LcMecfut9x7zJyodWWP43YQ 
--known-validator 7XSY3MrYnK8vq693Rju17bbPkCN3Z7KvvfvJx4kdrsSY 
--known-validator Ft5fbkqNa76vnsjYNwjDZUXoTWpP7VYm3mtsaQckQADN 
--known-validator 9QxCLckBiJc783jnMvXZubK4wH86Eqqvashtrwvcsgkv 
--only-known-rpc 
--full-rpc-api 
--no-voting 
--ledger /mnt/ledger 
--accounts /mnt/accounts 
--log /home/sol/solana-rpc.log 
--rpc-port 8899 
--rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 
--private-rpc 
--dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 
--entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--expected-genesis-hash 4uhcVJyU9pJkvQyS88uRDiswHXSCkY3zQawwpjk2NsNY 
--wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record 
--limit-ledger-size
When I'm trying to run it I occured in this error:
[2024-12-08T16:15:26.309907688Z INFO  agave_validator::admin_rpc_service] started admin rpc service!
Failed to contact cluster entrypoint 147.28.180.247:8001: connection timed out
[2024-12-08T16:15:31.313285704Z INFO  agave_validator] Contacting 145.40.64.255:8001 to determine the validator's public IP address
Failed to contact cluster entrypoint 145.40.64.255:8001: connection timed out
[2024-12-08T16:15:36.317447350Z INFO  agave_validator] Contacting 34.83.231.102:8001 to determine the validator's public IP address
Failed to contact cluster entrypoint 34.83.231.102:8001: connection timed out
Unable to determine the validator's public IP address
How can I fix it? I have already tried with the --gossip  flag but no luck with that
Thank you everyone

Your startup script mixes testnet and mainnet info -- the --expected-genesis-hash is from testnet, but the entrypoints are for mainnet. Try to update your parameters to the following:
    --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d \

And also update the known validators to:
    --known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 \
    --known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ \
    --known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ \
    --known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S \

Info taken from https://docs.anza.xyz/clusters/available#mainnet-beta
